# aspnetboilerplate: How to implement dynamic module management?

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

How to implement dynamic module(plugin) installation/deletion in aspnetboilerplate?

suppose I create a separate class library project to implement versioning of project module
e.g. for a billing module(plugin) I create a separate class library project & a separate dbcontext within that and create multiple versions of that dll

for fine grained updates to the aspnetboilerplate application I want ability to deploy the dll dynamically,
I mean when I build new version of billing module(say v2) I want to deploy that dll only instead of deploying the whole aspnetboilerplate project.

how do I achieve this?

My requirement is to implement plugin kind of architecture in aspnetboilerplate.
plugin can be dynamically added or removed or upgraded to newer version through UI

[image]

-nitin

Comment: https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Plugin
Is that what you looking for?

Comment: yes, this is what I am looking for but how can I have a new plugin with own `dbcontext` and `UI`?